# While making a game launcher/updater I encountered a strange error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, updates

While making a game launcher/updater I encountered a strange error. The issue full error can be seen here:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
    at com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher.Updater.getLatestVersion(Updater.java:18)
    at com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher.RMLauncher.main(RMLauncher.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the code that I had:

**`RMLauncher.java`:**

```
package com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher;
/**
 * Created by afroraydude.
 * This Class runs the game
*/
public class RMLauncher {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] cmds;
    cmds = new String[]{"Game.exe", "CUSTOM_LAUNCHER"};
    try {
        System.out.println(Updater.getLatestVersion());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds).waitFor();
    }
}
```

**`Updater.java`:**

```
package com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by afroraydude
 */
public class Updater {

    private final static String versionURL = "http://afroraydude.com/rpgupdate/version.html";

    private final static String historyURL = "";

    public static String getLatestVersion() throws Exception
    {
        String data = getData(versionURL);
        return data.substring(data.indexOf("[version]")+9,data.indexOf("[/version]"));
    }
    public static String getWhatsNew() throws Exception
    {
        String data = getData(historyURL);
        return data.substring(data.indexOf("[history]")+9,data.indexOf("[/history]"));
    }
    private static String getData(String address)throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL(address);

        InputStream html = null;

        html = url.openStream();

        int c = 0;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");

        while(c != -1) {
            c = html.read();

            buffer.append((char)c);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

While making a game launcher/updater i encountered a strange error. The issue full error can be seen here:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
    at com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher.Updater.getLatestVersion(Updater.java:18)
    at com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher.RMLauncher.main(RMLauncher.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the code that I had:
RMLauncher.java

```
package com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher;
/**
 * Created by afroraydude.
 * This Class runs the game
*/
public class RMLauncher {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] cmds;
    cmds = new String[]{"Game.exe", "CUSTOM_LAUNCHER"};
    try {
        System.out.println(Updater.getLatestVersion());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds).waitFor();
    }
}
```

Updater.java

```
package com.afroraydude.rpg.launcher;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by afroraydude
 */
public class Updater {

    private final static String versionURL = "http://afroraydude.com/rpgupdate/version.html";

    private final static String historyURL = "";

    public static String getLatestVersion() throws Exception
    {
        String data = getData(versionURL);
        return data.substring(data.indexOf("[version]")+9,data.indexOf("[/version]"));
    }
    public static String getWhatsNew() throws Exception
    {
        String data = getData(historyURL);
        return data.substring(data.indexOf("[history]")+9,data.indexOf("[/history]"));
    }
    private static String getData(String address)throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL(address);

        InputStream html = null;

        html = url.openStream();

        int c = 0;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");

        while(c != -1) {
            c = html.read();

            buffer.append((char)c);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Allow me to state what should be happening. The application should print the version from the html file. But instead it is giving this error. I hope this is an issue on my part and not just some random weird thing that can't be fixed.

Comment: What's strange about it? Why do you think it shouldn't occur?

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to occur, it is supposed to print the version from the html file.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: How to calculate a length of string?

Comment: What nikpon? I don't understand.

Comment: What data do you actually receive in `getLatestVersion`?

Comment: David Conrad, I have not yet finished the classes. This code is based on [this tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190944-creating-an-updater-in-java/).

Comment: What did you find out when you debugged your code?

Comment: I would check the value of the `data` variable in that method, either in a debugger, or by printing it out before returning. Suspect it is either `null` or doesn't contain one of the substrings you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidConrad the same thing is found.

Comment: @fd. How would I check the value?

Comment: I don't know, how about `System.out.println(data);`???

Comment: @afroraydude You could print it to the console with `System.out.println("Data: " + data);`

Comment: that would require data to be public and data won't be public if it is public you recieve an illegal start of expression.

Comment: The `println` would go inside `getLatestVersion`, so data doesn't have to be public.

Answer (score 1):

To find the value between a `history` tag, you could use something like

```
String data = "<history>hello</history>";
int openPos = data.indexOf("history");
if (openPos >= 0) {
    int closePos = data.indexOf("/history", openPos + 1);
    if (closePos >= 0) {
        String str = data.substring(openPos + 8, closePos - 1);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
hello
```

Personally, I would prefer to use a regular expression [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) like

```
String data = "<history>hello</history>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<history>(\\S+)</history>",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output is (also)

```
hello
```

Comment: @afroraydude Replace your version of `version` and `history` with this code and you won't get that `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` with input that contains valid version and history tags. Your version doesn't work.

Comment: for version, do i just change the <history></history> to <version></version>

Comment: @afroraydude Yes. You can reuse the `Pattern` instances, so you might compile and save those once. So a `Pattern historyPattern = Pattern.compile("<history>(\\S+)</history>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` and a `Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("<version>(\\S+)</version>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` should do it.